# Active user account after administration's confirmation

Tags: users

How to, by using module [Profile2 Registration Path](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath), the user's account becomes active after it is activated by the administrator. The administrator should get email when user creates new account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need a contrib module for that. You can set " Visitors, but administrator approval is required" under "Who can create accounts" on `admin/config/people/accounts`.

As for sending e-mail, create an advanced action at `admin/config/system/actions` and then set it on `admin/structure/trigger/user` to be triggered by account creation.

The core Action and Trigger modules are all that are required for that.